# Capturing text body within repeated header-footer pattern using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a string from a script using C# .NET that appears as such (**bolded** below are fixed syntax ie SOMEHEADER and END_SOMEHEADER):

Start of script:

---

**SOMEHEADER** header1

*//some syntax to be added here*

**END_SOMEHEADER**

**SOMEHEADER** header2

*//some syntax to be added here*

**END_SOMEHEADER**

---

...(and the above pattern will be repeated)...

End of script

"header1" and "header2" in the above example are the names (any alphanumeric characters) for the respective SOMEHEADER. I am actually interested to capture the text body (refer italicized text above) and store them in a collection with header names (ie in this example would be "header1" and "header2") as the key.

I believe that Regex is able to solve the above problem, but I have been struggling to come up with an appropriate regex pattern, and I only managed to come up with this

```
(?:SOMEHEADER)\s*(?<someheadername>[a-zA-Z0-9._]+)(?<body>(?:.|\n)*)(?:END_SOMEHEADER)
```

which does not fix the problem.

Appreciate some kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

^SOMEHEADER\s*([0-9A-Z._]+)\n*(.+)\n*END_SOMEHEADER
Group 1 gives the header and Group 2 gives the textblock. You can name the groups if you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain a bit in detail on how I could achieve it? I am trying to parse a script where the pattern requires the head-tail (SOMEHEADER-END_SOMEHEADER) pair to exist and such head-tail pair can be repeated.

Comment: To get more than 1 match uses MatchCollections and Regex.Matches instead of Match and Regex.Match